# Django ajax post throws 500 error on web host but works on localhost

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am able to send JSON data using AJAX on the local server, but, when I run the same site on the webserver, ajax post throws 500 (Internal Server Error).
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('recievejson/', views.recievejson, name='recievejson'),
]
```

views.p

```
@csrf_exempt       
def recievejson(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # This condition is satisfied when hosted on localhost.
        import json
        print("DATA RECIEVED")
        print(request.body)
    else: # This condition is satisfied when onsted on web server.
        message = "Data not recieved"
    return JsonResponse({"message": 'http://domain name com/static/text/'+message})
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/recievejson",
         type: "POST",
         data: data,
         processData: false,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            success: function(data) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS");
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log("fail");
                }
         });
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You say it works on localhost? From my understanding this should also not work on localhost... Anyway your url pattern is like `path('recievejson/', ...)` and you make a request to `url: "/recievejson",`, See the problem? you need to be making a request to `url: "/recievejson/",` (see the trailing slash)

Comment: For details about such errors take a look at django error log.

Comment: [Sun Apr 04 07:46:18.893069 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 36584:tid 139851872450304] [remote 37.111.135.9:28823] Not Found: /recievejson/